# INotifyPropertyChanged doesnt fire when property changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bool value that gets updated and the INotifyPropertyChanged event doesnt fire properly. It gets to the IF portion and steps over because it sees a null being passed. I did add using System.ComponentModel at the top of the class

The first portion:

```
  public class ToolTipInortfyPropertyChange : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    private bool form15TooltipShow;
    public bool Form15TooltipShow
    {
        get { return form15TooltipShow; }
        set
        {
            form15TooltipShow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Form15TooltipShow");
        }

    }
```

and then the second portion all in the same class

```
 public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

when I step in the code it gets to the "Set" portion then jumps to the OnPropertyChanged and skips the if so my view doesnt get updated with another event needing the bool

Tx

Comment: Then `PropertyChanged` event is *null* as it most likely has no subscribers. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do and in what context?

Comment: Why should you say anything if noone is listening? Why should you notify about property change if noone has subscribed to that PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Seems that nothing is subscribed to the event, what class do you expect to listen to it?

Comment: How are you binding to this property? Or aren't you trying to do that?

Comment: Your event raiser code is bad (that isn't the reason for your issue, but might cause another ones). You should either use a temporary for the delegate, or the null-conditional operator and `Invoke`.

Answer (score 4):

This the case with every event in c#, if no one subscribed to the event then it will be `null`. In this case it seems like no one subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event.

**PS:** I recommend putting the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute in the `OnPropertyChanged` method so you don't have to pass the name along manually every time. Like so:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

Notice how I made the method `protected` instead of public, we don't wan't just anyone being able to raise the event

**Edit:** Here's the full `OnPrertyChanged` method:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: It may help to explain what the `?.` operator does in this context, as the OP didn't use it in his question.

Answer (score 0):

When I step through the code I can see that

```
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

does execute and the value is no longer null so there must be a "listener" I gather. But the view doesnt update. The checkbox is on one form and the control that will receive the event from the checkbox is on another form. Its almost like 2 objects are created and they cant talk to each other because they are 2 different enteties. Is that possible when creating a new object of lets say type person on form 1 and the same on form 2. They will be distinct wouldnt they?

I created a whole new project and made it as simple as possible. Textbox on form1 and textbox on form 2 and try to pass text between these 2 forms. The  line

```
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

excecutes with no Null value but the view doesnt update.

Here is the XAML

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CheckBoxState ,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

and I have tried all kinds of different options like ASYNC etc. The result is always the same. I even removed the code behind from the forms and did the binding on the XAML

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <local:CheckBoxClass x:Key="CheckBoxFinder" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CheckBoxFinder}}">
```

I believe this worked fine because intelensense automatically comes up after I type PATH=
 then the only property listed pops up.

any advice  would be appreciated. 
tx

Ok just used the EXACT same code and simply added another textbox to form1. So form1 has 2 textboxes. I bound them exactly as previously only difference is the controls sending and receiving are on the same form. And guess what... It worked.

The problem arises when 2 forms need to pass data. Its like 2 objects are created and they cant communicate. I'm sure this is common knowledge to all the seasoned guys / gals. But  how do I use one object between these forms so they will be synced? Wish I knew this before could have asked my question more concisely

Comment: WPF does not have forms, so what do you mean with forms? If you bind both to the same property in the ViewModel this should not be a problem.

Comment: Old habbits die hard. I meant window. The solution was easy. The first form created an object from a class. The second form created an object from the same class. Even though both objects were created from the same blueprint they reside in different locations in memory. So databinding couldnt happen between 2 different windows. The solution is to create the object in the first window and pass it to the second window.  TargetWindow.MasterGrid.DataContex = OriginatingWindow.DataContex; Now they share the same object and databinding will happen